# Como organizar o HTML?

Tags: html, css

Observe a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso colocar a letra "á" aqui no meio como mostra a seta, mas não sei como fazer isso, já tentei de várias formas. O código abaixo é o meu HTML:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Período:</label>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-2">
                       <input autocomplete="off" id="idPeriodoInicio" class="form-control monthPicker listar_uj" name="periodoInicio" id="periodoInicio"  placeholder="Período Inicial"> 
                      </div>
                       <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input autocomplete="off"  id="idPeriodoFim" class="form-control monthPicker listar_uj" name="periodoFim" id="periodoFim" placeholder="Período Final">
                      </div> 
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Ao invés de utilizar row's e col's, tente utilizar a classe form-inline nos componentes.

Comment: como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Vou responder como pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <div class="form-inline">
   <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label">Período:</label>
     <input autocomplete="off" id="idPeriodoInicio" class="form-control monthPicker listar_uj" name="periodoInicio" id="periodoInicio"  placeholder="Período Inicial"> 
     <input autocomplete="off"  id="idPeriodoFim" class="form-control monthPicker listar_uj" name="periodoFim" id="periodoFim" placeholder="Período Final">
  </div>
```

Agora vá adequando a sua necessidade com os estilos do css.

Comment: vale a pena incluir o css por trás da classe "form-inline", você está assumindo que o OP está usando bootstrap. Além de poder confundir outras pessoas mais leigas.

Comment: Entendi que ele usou bootstrap pelas outras classes implementadas (form-control, control-label, form-group, row e col's), sendo assim dei a dica utilizando o bootstrap.